Error : Failed to Fetch. Only on Mobile Web
Im running EC2 ubuntu server and my website is served over HTTPS using NGINX with a proper (LetsEncrypt) certificate. I'm using Node.js and Vercel.app to develop the website;
The front-end is being hosted on a subdomain, e.g. https://admin.example.com, while original domain is http://example.com
The website works on a PC web browser but the problem occurs when using a mobile web browser. It returns the following error when I try to access the URL:

error : failed to fetch

I checked CORS. Which I tried on node code only, tried it on NGINXwith it or NGINXalone.
now CORS setting is applied on both back-end and NGINX.
Only thing I'm suspecting for now is that the DNS server is certified for example.co.kr while front domain is using admin.example.co.kr
could that be causing this problem which only mobile device makes failed to fetch error?
I've also checked NGINX.
the log from mobile requests are below
    109.202.99.36 - - [18/Jun/2024:02:43:28 +0000] 
    "GET /config.yaml HTTP/1.1"                404 150 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /.ssh/id_ecdsa HTTP/1.1"              404 152 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"  
    "GET /etc/ssl/private/server.key HTTP/1.1" 404 159 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /.ssh/id_ed25519 HTTP/1.1"            404 155 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /web.config HTTP/1.1"                 404 150 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /dump.sql HTTP/1.1"                   404 148 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /.git/HEAD HTTP/1.1"                  404 149 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1"  404 160 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
    "GET /.env HTTP/1.1"                       404 143 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /config/production.json HTTP/1.1"     404 157 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /config/database.php HTTP/1.1"        404 154 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /backup.tar.gz HTTP/1.1"              404 152 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /backup.zip HTTP/1.1"                 404 150 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /.kube/config HTTP/1.1"               404 151 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET / HTTP/1.1"                           404 139 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /.svn/wc.db HTTP/1.1"                 404 150 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /backup.sql HTTP/1.1"                 404 150 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /.ssh/id_rsa HTTP/1.1"                404 150 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /wp-config.php HTTP/1.1"              404 152 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /server.key HTTP/1.1"                 404 149 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /etc/shadow HTTP/1.1"                 404 149 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /config.php HTTP/1.1"                 404 149 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /config.xml HTTP/1.1"                 404 150 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /secrets.json HTTP/1.1"               404 150 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1"                404 148 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /database.sql HTTP/1.1"               404 150 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /docker-compose.yml HTTP/1.1"         404 154 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /server-status HTTP/1.1"              404 151 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /config.json HTTP/1.1"                404 150 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /config.yml HTTP/1.1"                 404 149 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /.env.production HTTP/1.1"            404 153 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 
    "GET /.aws/credentials HTTP/1.1"           404 153 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"

I have no idea why mobile requests ask for such system files when it's requesting via same front URL.
the front code doesn't ask for such files at all
could this be a reason why mobile requests are making errors?
Or of course CORS could still be a problem.
please let me know if you think I'm missing something.
Im pretty new dealing with both codes and proxy especially with HTTPS.
Suggestions doesn't have to be a correct answer or solution for my problem. I'm learning so, if anything is suspicious, let me know I'll try it and it'll be thankful of-course
** added **
Here are my error logs from mobile device.
23-1b3e0fc6b991dd5e.js:1 Fetch finished loading: GET "https://admin.yjhorion.co.kr/?_rsc=qsrma".

layout-59b53b766e4a5b77.js:1 Fetch failed loading: GET "https://yjhorion.co.kr/auth".

page-d1c4f42e23a616bd.js:17 Fetch failed loading: GET "https://yjhorion.co.kr/CompQC/D".

 GET https://yjhorion.co.kr/auth net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERRORlayout-59b53b766e4a5b77.js:1 layout-59b53b766e4a5b77.js:1 
     
GET https://yjhorion.co.kr/CompQC/D net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR page-d1c4f42e23a616bd.js:17 


sorry for messy log.
i rearannged it in a readable way but the change did not apply. im fixing it

Share the full error you got o nthe client side.

Are you sure the requests posted are from your testing client? The dump shown looks more like bots/malicious users trying to find vulnerabilities on the webserver

@Evert ERROR-log on mobile device says 'Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR'

@DarkBee Yeah It looks like it. I wrote both front and back code and tried the test myself in real-time. It is so weird why it asks for such env files. I'll check if my device has some virus or sth

So that sounds like a misconfigured HTTPS server or you use HTTPS and it should be HTTP instead. If the url and protocol is for sure correct on the client side, try opening the server url with curl (with the exact same url) and share the exact error you get there.

@DarkBee is correct, those are just bots trying to break into your server by testing known vulnerabilities. This is pretty normal

Actually since you shared the real URL, i took a look. Your SSL is misconfigured in what's probably nginx. You are running on port 443 but you are not running a HTTPS server there, it's a unencrypted HTTP on port 443. You can test with http://your-server:443/ which does work and https://your-server/ which doesn't. It's not enough to just open port 443.

@Evert Thank you. I Think Im kinda getting what you are telling me but still a bit confused.
I tried both url 'https://admin.yjhorion.co.kr/compqc' and 'http://admin.yjhorion.co.kr:443/compqc'
then both url navigates me to https://admin.yjhorion.co.kr/compqc
(I haven't tried admin.yjhorion.co.kr since it doens't send any request on main page.)
I thought Nginx navigates :80 requests into :443 and it seems like it is working.

sorry for confusion. I have little knowledge about https and programming yet.
Im not fully understanding what your point is.

@Evert NVM. Thanks for advice and help. I guess what I should do is either run a https server or fix my configuration with Nginx so it could run and handle https encrypt.

@JaeHyunYoo yes fix nginx to support HTTPS, or switch to HTTP without encryption and run on port 80.

Thank you for helping. I fixed its configuration and now both https:// and http:// works and it prints "hello world!"
However, Im still struggling with my mobile connection.
both http:// and https:// does not show.
Im researching what difference is making this.
if anyone has any clue. please let me know

Alright. There were 2 problems and solved.
First, My Nginx conf was wrong.
I fixed it so both http and https were available.
Second, I was using Subdomain of my backend DNS server.
Subdomain and backend domain were sharing the same IP but FrontEnd and BackEnd were deployed separately.
So I deleted subdomain settings for FrontEnd Server which is deployed on Vercel and it's working just fine now.
Im still not sure why it worked fine on PC web tho.
I'll add it if I get to know why.
